# What is %2 in $id%2

Tags: php, syntax

What does %2 do in the following php?

```
$id=(int)@$_REQUEST['id'];
echo ( !($id%2) )?
    "{'id':$id,'success':1}":
    "{'id':$id,'success':0,'error':'Could not delete subscriber'}";
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`%` is the [modulus operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). `% 2` is therefore the remainder after division by two, so either 0 (in case `$id` was even) or 1 (in case `$id` was odd).

The expression `!($id % 2)` uses automatic conversion to a boolean value (in which 0 represents false and everything non-zero represents true) and negates the result. So the result of that expression is true if `$id` was even and `false` if it was odd. That also determines what the `echo` prints there. Apparently an even value for `$id` signals success.

A slightly more elaborate but maybe easier to understand way to write above statement would be:

```
if ($id % 2 == 0)
   echo "{'id':$id,'success':1}";
else
   echo "{'id':$id,'success':0,'error':'Could not delete subscriber'}";
```

But that spoils all the fun with the ternary operator. Still, I'd have written the condition not as `!($id%2)` but rather as `($id % 2 != 0)`. Mis-using integers for boolean values leads to some hard to diagnose errors sometimes :-)

Answer (score 2):

[`%` is the modulo operator.](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) So `$id % 2` will return `0` if the value of `$id` is even and `1` if the value is odd.

Answer (score 0):

This is checking if the ID is even. If it's even, then PHP will evaluate that 0 as false.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Modulus section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) for PHP, Basically if it's Modulus 2 the Success else error

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, `%` will give you the remainder after dividing by that number. In effect this code block will echo "success = 1" if the id is even (or not a number, or not defined(!!)), and "success = 0" if the id is odd.